# Emulating an Operating System inside web browser

Tags: browser, 64-bit, operating-systems, emulation

Is it possible to natively emulate an x64 operating system inside a web browser?

Comment: How do you envisage this would work?

Comment: @Tetsujin quite straightforward? See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. Proof by example: Fabrice Bellard's [JSLinux](https://bellard.org/jslinux/) can boot x86 Linux 3.12.0, Windows 200, FreeDOS. Probably other OSes as well.

Technically, what Bellard did here is cross-compile his tinyEMU for WASM (or JavaScript, if not supported) through emscripten (and of course, write a buckload of glue so that the graphical display ends up on your screen, etc). TinyEMU is a small emulator he wrote (QEMU was originally written by him, too).

Comment: Clever… but I bet that's not what the OP wanted ;)

Comment: I think they asked for an emulated x86 operating system? We must have both different readings of the question then!

Comment: @Tetsujin That was exactly what I was asking.